# Add custom number of divs with Angular

Tags: angularjs

Imagine a scope variable which is read and does change: `total_number`. I want to build an equal number of divs if `total_number<=10` or the half amount if `10< total_number<=20`. I guess I have to use a directive, however I do not know how to define the different number of divs...May I use link and what do I have to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made an example by `directive` , hope it works for you. Any questions let me know plz.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.total_number = 10;
  })
  .directive('divBuilder', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        count: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var count = Number(scope.count);
        if (!count || count <= 0) {
          return false;
        }
        if (count > 10 && count <= 20) {
          count = Math.floor(count / 2);
        }
        var div = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          div += '<div class="line">' + (i + 1) + '</div>';
        }

        element.append(div);
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
div.line {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Single Demo</title>
  <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div-builder count="{{total_number}}"></div-builder>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Adding some commentary to your solution (how it works / what it does) would be a good idea.